# Metropolis sampling with stochastic estimation of component of probability density

Tags: sampling, markov-process, metropolis-hastings, importance-sampling

Consider the probability distribution

\begin{align}
p(x) = \frac{1}{Z} x^2 e^{-x^2 / 2}
\end{align}

where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $Z$ is a normalization factor so that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, p(x) = 1$.

I want to use a Markov Chain Monte Carlo algorithm (e.g. a Metropolis
algorithm, for which we don't need to know the normalization factor $Z$) to
sample from this distribution, but I want to stochastically estimate the $x^2$
factor outside of the exponential by noticing that

\begin{align}
x^2 = \int \mathcal{D}\phi \; e^{- \frac{\phi^2}{x^2}}
\end{align}

where $\phi \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}\phi \equiv \frac{d\Re
\phi}{\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{d\Im \phi}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Therefore I want to sample from
the new joint distribution density

\begin{align}
p(x, \phi) = \frac{1}{Z} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{\phi^2}{x^2}}
\end{align}

knowing that expectation values of a function $f(x)$ over $p(x,\phi)$ will be
the same as those over $p(x)$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}_{p(x,\phi)}[f(x)] = \mathbb{E}_{p(x)}[f(x)]$.

The following Random Walk Metropolis algorithm, where I use a normal
distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ to propose the next sample $x'$ of the Markov
chain, seems to generate a Markov chain following the correct distribution:

1. Generate $\eta \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$, where $\mathcal{CN}$ denotes a complex
   normal distribution.
2. Do a change of variables to set $\phi = x \eta$ where $\phi$ will be constant
   throughout the Metropolis step.
3. Propose a new sample $x' = x + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim
      \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $x$ is the previous sample in the Markov chain.
4. Accept the new sample with probability $p_{\text{acc}}=\min \left\{ 1, \frac{p(x',\phi)}{p(x,\phi)} \right\}$

Iterating these steps seems to correctly generate a Markov chain of samples
following $p(x)$:

[image: histogram of MC samples of p(x)]

A modification of this algorithm using Hamiltonian Monte Carlo instead of the
random walk is used in High Energy Particle Physics, particularly in Lattice QCD
simulations, where one needs to stochastically estimate a matrix determinant
(which depends on $x$) in the same way as we are estimating the $x^2$ factor
outside of the exponential in this toy example. The words that are normally used
to describe this algorithm are something like "sampling $x$ with an additional
background field $\phi$". I would like to know if there is a formal way to
address this algorithm where part of the probability density needs to be
estimated stochastically, and also which conditions are needed for the algorithm
to sample correctly from the distribution, maybe giving an intuition of why this should work. I thought it was similar to [slice
sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_sampling), but doesn't seem to be
quite the same thing.

Some references would be appreciated as well.

Comment: $\phi$ is usually called an auxiliary variable in simulation books, we call it demarginalization in [our book](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR), and this is a form of slice sampling, if with another auxiliary  variable than the slice Uniform one.

Comment: Note that simulating from $f(x)\propto x^2\exp\{-x^2/w\}$ is straightforward via the change of variable $Y=X^2$ which is distributed as a Gamma $G(1/2,1/2)$ rv.